# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function, than loading fixtures using ContainerAwareInterface

Tags: php, symfony, containers

When loading fixtures in Symfony 2.8, I am getting the following error when I implement `ContainerAwareInterface`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\User()
```

If I do not use this interface, this error does not appear. I took the example code from official [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

The file:

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface; 
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use MeetingBundle\Entity\User;

//C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym_prog\just2\src\MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUsers01Loader.php


/*
  Class LoadUsers01
 @package Meeting\DataFixtures\ORM
 */
class LoadUsers01Loader extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface {

     /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;


    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    /*
      {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            $fuser = new User();
            $fuser->setUsername('name'.$i);
            $fuser->setEmail('g.statkute'.$i.'@gmail.com');
            $fuser->setIsActive(1); //also tried to use true
                $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
                $encodedPsswd = $encoder->encodePassword($user, 'pswd'.$i);
            //$fuser->setPassword('pswd'.$i);
            $fuser->setPassword($encodedPsswd);
            $manager->persist($fuser);
            $this->addReference('fuser:name'.$i, $fuser);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

        public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The full error:

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym_prog\just2>php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y
  > purging database
  > loading [1] MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUsers01
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\User() in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym_prog\just2\src\MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUsers01.php on line 40
```

I don't know how `ContainerAwareInterface` could cause this error? If I do not implement it and use a plain password without encoders the fixtures get loaded into the database.

Actually, ignoring this error and workign further i start getting other namespace errors. FOr example, symfony tries to load class "ArrayCollection" from namespace "MeetingBundle\Entity\Doctrine\Common\Collections". There is smth wrong with namespaces. ow to fix this?

```
src\MeetingBundle\Entity\User.php
namespace MeetingBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tuser")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MeetingBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable

<...>
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

 public function __construct() {
 $this->roles = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
<...>
```

When creating a user gives me an error:

```
Attempted to load class "ArrayCollection" from namespace "MeetingBundle\Entity\Doctrine\Common\Collections".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection"?
```

Comment: I think you forgot about `new` before  `User()`.

Comment: If i use `$fuser = new MeetingBundle\Entity\User();` i am getting error ` [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]` :
  `Attempted to load class "User" from namespace "MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\MeetingBundle\Entity"`.
  `Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User" or "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tests\Fixtures\User"?`

Comment: If i use `$fuser = new User();` i am getting the error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]`, `Notice: Undefined variable: user`, although, i have on the top `use MeetingBundle\Entity\User;`

Comment: Something wron with namespaces in fixtures. how to fix this?

Comment: Finally worked. Seems the reason was in mispelling $user instead of $fuser.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you forgot about `new` operator before `User()`, therefore PHP treats it as a function call.

Change this line:

```
$fuser = User();
```

to:

```
$fuser = new User();
```

Further you're using `$user` variable which doesn't exists in line:

```
$encodedPsswd = $encoder->encodePassword($user, 'pswd'.$i);
```

You should change it to use `$fuser`:

```
$encodedPsswd = $encoder->encodePassword($fuser, 'pswd'.$i);
```

Comment: I am sorry, seems i forgot to paste it to question. `new` is in my code and it does not work. Thank you for notice about `$fuser` instead of `$user`. ANyway, correcting this, stil gives the same error, and namespace errors arose from other pices of code, as i added to the question.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
        $fuser = User();
```

and

```
 use MeetingBundle\Entity\User;
```

There is no `User` function in the `MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM` namespace. It's probably over in `MeetingBundle\Entity\User`, so you probably want

```
$fuser = MeetingBundle\Entity\User\User();
```

instead.

Comment: Using your advice `$fuser = MeetingBundle\Entity\User;` gives ` Error: Undefined constant 'MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\MeetingBundle\Ent
  ity\User'`

Comment: Using `$fuser = MeetingBundle\Entity‌​\User();` gives the same `[ Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException]` 
  :  `Attempted to call function "User" from namespace "MeetingBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\MeetingBundle\Entity".`

Comment: But, there is no errors if i do not extend from `ContainerAwareInterface`. How to get rid of this error? Nevertheless, i need container for password and other things. Generally, the code i use follows official documentation example and i gave link in the question to it.